# Problemas para validar usuario contra Active Directory desde PHP

Tags: php, ldap, activedirectory

Pues mi problema es el siguiente: tengo una aplicación que valida usuarios contra el Active Directory de mi oficina pero resulta que hay usuarios a los que se niega a validarlos y son los que empieza por F.

```
$ldapserver = 'AD';
$ldapuser      = 'user';  
$ldappass     = 'pass';
$ldaptree    = "OU=OU,DC=DC,DC=DC";
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
  
if($ldapconn) {
   // binding to ldap server
   ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
   ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
   $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

    if ($ldapbind) {
        $usuarioBuscar = "domain\fernan";
        $user_pass = "M4r$2023";
        ldap_bind($ldapconn, $usuarioBuscar, $user_pass);
    }
}
```

He creado diferentes usuarios con contraseñas iguales, distintas, que empiecen por F o por cualquier otra letra y solamente falla con los usuarios que empiezan por F. Lo sé, es loquísimo pero no sé qué más hacer.

Comment: Revisa que no te toque escapar ese ```\``` en el usuario y que esté interpretando el `\f` como algo más

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia. He probado lo que me dices y no, no es esto. Incluso lo he probado de esta otra manera '$usuarioBuscar = "ffernandez@dominio";' y sigue igual.

Comment: cambia las " por ' asi "domain\fernan" cambia a 'domain\fernan'

Comment: tambien puedes ir a registro de eventos del windows para verificar que las aciones de tu codigo esten bien, no valla a ser un problema de la configuracion del windows server, ahora la suerencia tambien va por https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ldap-escape.php pues puede que este interpretando como exprecion regular tendrias que escapar la info asi:  `$usuarioBuscar = ldap_escape("domain\fernan", null, LDAP_ESCAPE_DN);`
asi le dices que busque claramente un string

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la sugerencia del visor de eventos, no pensé en ello, pero no ha hecho más que empeorar la cosa. Si no escapo el `\f` parece como si no le llegara al AD la orden, no veo ningún error ahí, pero una vez escapada sí. Los datos a priori son correctos: el nombre de cuenta, el dominio de cuenta.
Seguiré investigando en este sentido, a ver si averiguo algo.

Answer (score 0):

En fin, que me han tenido loco una tarde entera y haciendo el ridículo aquí. El problema fue una mezcla de interpretación del `\f` y que le cambiaron la password al usuario sin avisarme y todas las pruebas las hice con la password incorrecta. En fin... Gracias por vuestra ayuda.